# jetty 8 - websockets : how do I get the client IP address?

Tags: java, jetty, websocket

Simple task. I'm using the websockets server implementation by jetty, and I have to get the client IP address, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is same as it always was, grab IP from `HTTPServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()` like this:

```
public class WSServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public WebSocket doWebSocketConnect(HttpServletRequest req, String str) {
        System.out.println("IP: "+ req.getRemoteAddr());
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session` I would go for:

```
session.getRemoteAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress();
```

Answer (score 1):

Without WebServletSocket:

```
public static String getClientIp(Session session) {
        String ip = session.getUserProperties().get("javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress").toString();
        int i1 = ip.indexOf("/");
        int i2 = ip.indexOf(":");
        return ip.substring(i1 + 1, i2);
    }
```

Comment: This does not work with IPv6 addresses. Better is InetSocketAddress ip = (InetSocketAddress)session.getUserProperties().get("javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress");
            return ip.getAddress().getHostAddress();

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for authentification purposes, you can get it like this:

This is just an example:

```
@Override
public boolean canPublish(BayeuxServer server, ServerSession client,
                          ServerChannel channel, ServerMessage messsage) {
  //
  BayeuxContext context=server.getContext();
  System.out.println(context.getRemoteAddress());
  return true;
}
```

Please keep in mind that `getRemoteAddress` returns an `InetSocketAddress` string. So you also have the port, which looks something like this:

```
/79.111.111.22:49372
```